# Search a page source for an attr, then find that attr's parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wanting to find the parent div ID in javascript (or jquery), by searching HTML src for a specific attribute, or text.

Let's say that we're using this code:

```
<div id="ad_creative_1" class="ad-div mastad" style="z-index: 1;">
<script>(function() {var loaded = function() {return yt && yt.www && yt.www.home && yt.www.home.ads;};window.masthead_ad_creative_iframe_1_workaround = function() {if (loaded()) {yt.www.home.ads.workaroundIE(this);}};window.masthead_ad_creative_iframe_1_onload = function() {if (!loaded()) {setTimeout(masthead_ad_creative_iframe_1_onload, 50);return;}yt.www.home.ads.workaroundLoad();};})();</script>

      <iframe id="ad_creative_iframe_1" src="http://ad-g.doubleclick.net/N4061/adi/com.ythome/_default;sz=970x250;tile=1;plat=pc;dc_dedup=1;kage=18;kar=3;kbsg=HPUS130404;kcr=us;kga=1001;kgender=m;kgg=1;klg=en;kmyd=ad_creative_1;"
              height="250" width="970"
              scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="z-index: 1"
              onload="masthead_ad_creative_iframe_1_onload();"
              onmouseover="masthead_ad_creative_iframe_1_workaround(this)"
              onfocus="masthead_ad_creative_iframe_1_workaround(this)"></iframe>
        <script>
    (function() {
          var ord = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000000000000000);
          var adIframe = document.getElementById("ad_creative_iframe_1");
          adIframe.src = "http://ad-g.doubleclick.net/N4061/adi/com.ythome/_default;sz=970x250;tile=1;plat=pc;dc_dedup=1;kage=18;kar=3;kbsg=HPUS130404;kcr=us;kga=1001;kgender=m;kgg=1;klg=en;kmyd=ad_creative_1;ord=" + ord + "?";
    })();
  </script>

    </div>
```

Without knowing that the parent div is ad_creative_1, is it possible (and if so, how would i go about it?) to figure out the parent div by searching for a keyword within the source?

Say doubleclick.net is our keyword.

Can I search an html pages source, find doubleclick.net, and return the parent div of the section that has doubleclick.net in it?

How would i go about this?

Comment: Do you have any knowledge of the iframe id?

Comment: No. The only knowledge I have is that doubleclick.net is included in the source somewhere.

Comment: Note, doing anything with this div that would cause the iframe to reload, such as moving it, will cause invalid impressions which is probably against the TOS of the ad service you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the "attribute contains" selector, and then just get the parent :

```
var parent = $('[src*="doubleclick.net"]').parent();
```

And for Gods sake don't post your actual adsense code or click it to test stuff, or move it or change it, as that will just end up with your account being closed.

Comment: What is, my [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/HdfjX/) shows actual ads, that's why I did'nt post it ?